# I can't remember the title of this book. YA about people who turn into panthers

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for a book (possibly YA) where the female character owns a bookshop in a small town in America the male character is introduced when he buys a very old house near to the town. They start dating and she starts getting stalked by someone she doesn't know, so he vows to protect her. She then finds out that he can turn into a panther. I started reading it at a bookshop and got about 1/4 of the way in and put it down. I absolutely loved it and can't remember what it was called or who wrote it. Anyone got a clue?